# C# Sharepoint Find text in string with Camlex

Tags: linq, sharepoint, caml

I want to check a text in string. And use the following code:

```
var expressions = new List<Expression<Func<SPListItem, bool>>>();
expressions.Add(x => !((string)x["Name"]).Contains("test"));
var camlQuery = Camlex.Query().WhereAny(expressions).ToString();
```

**and an error occurred:**

> An exception of type 'CamlexNET.NonSupportedExpressionException' occurred in Camlex.NET.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Expression

```
x => (Convert(g.get_Item("Name")).Contains("test") == False)
```

can not be translated into CAML

Comment: Witch version of Camlex ?

Comment: `x => (Convert(g.get_Item("Name")).Contains("test") == False)` What is the variable `g`? Should that be `x`?